# Javascript unit testing framework that doesn't work in strict mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing

Is there a way to unit test code from not strict mode. Most of the testing frameworks, mocha, jest, etc are strict mode only. My code involves use of eval that needs non-strict mode scope that I cannot rewrite into strict mode compatible form. Any idea or do I need to write my own unit testing framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Karma with jasmine. Setting it to browser mode means no modules and no strict mode, yay.